# Why doesn't my POST variable arrive after this.form.submit();?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form that submits after a button is pressed. The problem is - the button that has the `this.form.submit()` function attached doesn't send the POST variable...

```
<form method= "post" action="timestable_submit.php">    
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $f;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="<?php echo $s;?>">

    <input type="submit" name="sub" id="btn" value="<?php echo $d;?>" 
         onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();">
    <input type="submit" name="sub" id="btn2" value="<?php echo $w1e;?>">         
    <input type="submit" name="sub" id="btn3"  value="<?php echo $w2e; ?>">
</form>
```

When I assign a variable from the `$_POST['sub']` - I get nothing...

Any ideas? It works if I don't have the `onclick="this.disable=true; this.form.submit();"` line

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. This is about a variable not passing on the POSTing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/140/)**.

Change button type to `button` instead of `submit` because you're submiting the form programmatically using `this.form.submit()` :

```
<input type="button" name="sub" id="btn" value="<?php echo $d;?>" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();">
```

And better if you could separate your logic and use `submit` event :

```
<input type="submit" name="sub" id="btn" value="<?php echo $d;?>"/>

var form = document.forms[0]; 
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
     document.getElementById('btn').disabled=true;
})
```

**NOTE :** `.disabled=true;` has almost no effect here because the page wil be redirected to `timestable_submit.php`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: HI there - this doesn't work either. Same thing happens.

Comment: Check my update, you could check the console and you'll find that the variables are sent...

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a go. The ' this.disable=true; ' is needed as it prevents multiple clicks of the button (which results in additional game points at the receiving page!).

Comment: :) i see that why I use _has **almost** no effect_, ok let me know if it works finally